# Capturing "Delete" Keypress with jQuery

Tags: jquery, keypress

When using the example code from the jQuery documentation for the keypress event handler, I'm unable to capture the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. The snippet below is going to log `0` when the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key is pressed in FireFox:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);       
});
```

Seems there's gotta be a way to capture the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, but it's an ambiguous term so Google isn't proving to be much help with it.

Comment: WIth Jquery: `$(document).keyup( function(e) { if(e.key == 'Backspace' || e.key == 'Delete') { ... } });`

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `keypress` event, but the `keyup` or `keydown` event because the `keypress` event is intended for real (printable) characters. `keydown` is handled at a lower level so it will capture all nonprinting keys like <kbd>delete</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: ```keyup``` would be do the job better.

Comment: @atilkan no, the user expects feedback on `keydown`, not `keyup`. All text editors perform actions when a key is pressed, not when it's released.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert In my case program can't catch the  last pressed char.

Comment: same as atilkan, so i use keyup

Answer (score 87):

```
$('html').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        alert('Delete key released');
    }
});
```

<sup>Source: [javascript char codes key codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) from www.cambiaresearch.com</sup>

Comment: It should be `alert('Delete Key Released')`.

Comment: if somebody uses keypress instead of keyup has suggested by Tod then you would get keycode == 46 event against . key (dot). but it works well with keyUp. Thanks

Comment: As pointed out in another answer, the `.keyCode` is deprecated.

Answer (score 39):

Javascript Keycodes

- **e.keyCode** == 8 for <kbd>backspace</kbd>
- **e.keyCode** == 46 for <kbd>forward backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> button in PC's

<sup>Except this detail Colin & Tod's answer is working.</sup>

Comment: It should be **e.keyCode** and not e.KeyCode

Answer (score 27):

## event.key === "Delete"

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. No more arbitrary number codes!

> NOTE: The old properties (`.keyCode` and `.which`) are Deprecated.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
    if (key === "Delete") {
        // Do things
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 2):

You can track the delete/ backspace key with jQuery as follow:

```
 $(document).keyup(function(e){
   if(e.key === "Backspace") {
    alert('Delete key/ backspace');
   }
 });
```