# jQuery: how to capture keypress key using live()

Tags: jquery, live, keypress

I need to capture a tab keypress event on some dynamic inputs, but the normal syntax using the keypress event doesn't seem to be catching the key code.

```
$('input').live('keypress', function (e) {
   if ( e.which == 9 )
       alert( 'Tab pressed' );
});
```

This seems to be catching 0 as the keypress when I go through the debugger in firebug no matter which key I press.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try it with .keyCode instead of .which:

```
$('input').live('keypress', function (e) {
   if ( e.keyCode == 9 ){
       alert( 'Tab pressed' );
    }
});
```

Seem to work ;)

Answer (score 9):

Try listening for `keyup` or `keydown` instead of `keypress` ([per this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116244/capturing-delete-keypress-with-jquery))

Comment: Indeed. quirksmode also has information on browser compatibility of the events, and particular browser quirks with certain keys. I've opted for `keydown` in my code.