# jQuery doesn't detect "left" keypress inside input box

Tags: jquery

My code is

```
$('input').live('keypress', function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 37) console.log("left key pressed");
    else console.log("some other key press");
});
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/4RKeV/

This detects keypresses, but not the left keypress (keyCode 37). How can I detect left keypress?

Comment: Works fine for me in FireFox 6.0

Comment: I see this is browser specific. I'm running Chrome 13. Should probably file a bug.

Comment: Change keypress to keydown. (See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165981/jquery-how-to-capture-keypress-key-using-live)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: don't use the `keypress` event. Use `keydown` or `keyup` instead.

The `keypress` event is not covered by any official specification. As such, `keypress` does not have well-defined behavior, will not work the same way across browsers, and will act capriciously and unpredictably. ([Read more <sup>[quirksmode.org]</sup>](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html))

As an alternative to `keypress`, you should use one of these events:

- [`keydown` <sup>[w3c spec]</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keydown) -- This triggers when a key is pressed down and continues to trigger while the key is held down.
- [`keyup` <sup>[w3c spec]</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keyup) -- This triggers when the key is lifted up.

I would probably fix it by using `keydown` because it is probably closer to what you were expecting `keypress` to do:

```
$('input').live('keydown', function(e) { 
   if (e.which === 37) { console.log("left key pressed"); }
   else { console.log("some other key press"); }
});
```

---

P.S. I changed `e.keyCode` to `e.which`, because it is more cross-browser compliant.

Comment: Great. So why doesn't `keypress` detect it anyway?

Comment: @Randomblue it's just not a standardized event, so its implementations vary. Some browsers simply don't trigger `keypress` with arrow keys.

Answer (score 3):

Change your binding event to `keyup`:

```
$('input').live('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 37) console.log("left key pressed");
    else console.log("some other key press");
});
```

Comment: It all comes down to whatever browser implementation it is. In IE9 at least, the event simply isnt triggered on that key press.

Comment: Hum. But isn't jQuery meant to harmonize this?

Comment: It's probably attached a handler to the keypress event sure (across browser implementations). However, it's probably IE9 which doesnt even invoke the event to reach the handler. jQuery just makes it easy to attach to the event.