# Detect delete key on the entire page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to detect a delete key over any portion of the page.  I have this code...

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

but I can't seem to get the event to fire at all..

Comment: Is there a javascript error on the page? The code you gave works for me... (though it'll log the event object, not the key you're after)

Answer (score 2):

You should check on key up (if possible).

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 46) {
      // Do it
    }
});
```

As for the event handler not working, it does when I try it, is there anything that is stopping it from being fired? JavaScript error? Something stopping the event from bubbling up (such as `e.stopPropagation()`)?

Answer (score 1):

Found this [Capturing "Delete" Keypress with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116244/capturing-delete-keypress-with-jquery)

```
console.log(e.which);
```

This worked for me:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
});
```

Delete key is 46 as per console.log

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
   console.log(e);
   var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
   if(keyCode == 46){
           //delet key pressed
   }
});
```