# How to clear a read only jQuery date picker textbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

We have a JQuery date picker control on a read only text box.  We make the textbox read only so users can't enter their own dates.  This works great but we want to provide the users the option to clear out the contents of the text box after they have selected a date.

How can you do this?  Apparently this functionality used to be built into the control but was [removed](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4162).

Note: we disable input into the textbox using:

```
$("#text-box").keypress(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

**Update**: I solved this with a slight variation of the selected answer:

```
    myTextBox.keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8) {
            //Delete and backspace clear text 
            $(this).val(''); //Clear text
            $(this).datepicker("hide"); //Hide the datepicker calendar if displayed
            $(this).blur(); //aka "unfocus"
        }

        //Prevent user from manually entering in a date - have to use the datepicker box
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: you should have answered to your question instead of updating solution in question and marking wrong solution as answer. It will definitely save time to many users like me who have spent hours to implementing your `marked answer` and then finding out that it was not correct answer. and correct answer is in question as update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about excluding [keys](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx) thats user use to clear textbox like 'del', 'backspace' etc.?

```
$("#text-box").keypress(function (e)
{
  switch(e.keyCode) { 
          case 46:  // delete
          case 8:  // backspace
            break;
          default:
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
       }
});
```

Comment: keypress does not work for delete and backspace actually. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1116253/2660342

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#text-box").bind('keypress keydown', function (e) {
  var tag = e.target.tagName;
  if (e.which === 8 || e.which === 46) { 
    $(this).val(''); 
    $(this).datepicker("hide"); 
    $(this).blur(); 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

This should work on browsers that [don't trigger keypress events for "delete" keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116244/capturing-delete-keypress-with-jquery?rq=1).