# Setting pc delete button with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to catch the event with javascript or jquery when user presses to the delete button in keyboard. Is this possible?

Comment: thanks,can you give me an example?

Comment: for example if delete pressed alert a message I am fresh for jquery

Comment: I solve this problem sucs as `  $('html').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 46)
            alert('Delete Key Pressed');
    });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're being told that this is impossible?

The delete key is 46, so this should work:

```
$('html').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 46){
        //delete key has been pressed.
    }
})
```

Also note: You should be using either the keyup or keydown event rather than keypress.  keypress is intended for real character. 'keyup'/'keydown' is handled at a lower level so it will capture all non-printing keys like DEL and ENTER.

Source is here: [Capturing "Delete" Keypress with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116244/capturing-delete-keypress-with-jquery)

Comment: You're missing a `;`. Use `which` (it's shorter!) (Kidding)

Comment: 'Semicolons in JavaScript are optional': http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/  Take a read!

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan I'm aware of the limitations with minification.  In this instance it would make no difference.  For reference: many JS compilers/minifiers will strip unnecessary semi-colons, including the YUI Compressor.

Comment: Glad to hear it @ƏfsunXəmmədli - feel free to open up more questions in the future if you need further guidance from people here.  If your question has been answered, do remember to put a green tick against the relevant answer so that anyone coming to the same problem in the future can find the answer as easily as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 46)alert('Delete Key Pressed')
})
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116244/capturing-delete-keypress-with-jquery)

Comment: jQuery will handle `which` like all other charcode keycode guys.