# How to trigger delete key in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am looking for a way to trigger the delete key on jQuery. However, for example, the whole selection (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>) works well, The <kbd>Delete</kbd> key does not work.

Below is a part of my code:

```
var ctrlA = $.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 65, ctrlKey:true } ),
    e = $.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 46 } );

....
$( editor.getBody() ).trigger( ctrlA );
$( editor.getBody() ).trigger( e );
```

This will make the entire selection but it will not be deleted.

How to trigger the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key in jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing "Delete" Keypress with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116244/capturing-delete-keypress-with-jquery)

Comment: @Riya OP wants to cause it, not capture it.